# Android Market Licensing service

Tags: android, android-lvl, in-app-billing

I am trying to make module in-app-billing for my application. There is one thing I want to know before develop in-app-billing module.

: Do I need to integrate the Licensing Verification Library in my application which is having in-app-billing module?

If I didn't integrate LVL, will work in-app-billing module on my application ?

Actually I haven't realized what is good for my application if I integrate LVL.

Can you suggest me ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to.

But what you possibly want to implement is your own security system, which is working on your own server in order not to be cheated by hackers, who can decompile your apk, find the key and get your goods for free.

See the [billing integration article](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_integrate.html), there are couple of words about it in the end.